# How can I save a matrix which grows in time?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, file-format

I have a 3D matrix whose third dimension is time, and it grows as time goes on. One way to save this on file in real-time would be to use this format:

```
# Created by Octave 6.3.0, Wed Sep 01 10:30:13 2021 BST <pietrom@UNKNOWN>
# name: A
# type: matrix
# ndims: 3
 3 4 2
 1
 5
 9
 2
 6
 10
 3
 7
 11
 4
 8
 12
 13
 17
 21
 14
 18
 22
 15
 19
 23
 16
 20
 24
```

where the time dimension is the third one. Here I show 2 time steps.

To add another time step, I should update the line where the matrix size is specified, i.e. going from "3 4 2" to "3 4 3", and append the new data at the end of the file.

However this approch is not optimal. Is there a (text based) Octave/MATLAB file format which does not require to update the header for every insertion?

Comment: Saving to file in real time is not a great idea... The best way is either to save every X datapoints in one go, save every X seconds, or just save in the end in bulk.

Comment: @AnderBiguri - My question applies both when saving line by line and in blocks (every X datapoints).

Comment: Why do you need to update the matrix size? You know that the first two dimensions are constant and, if you save your matrix as a row vector instead of a column vector, you can just count the number of line after the header to know the size of the third dimension.

Comment: @MatteoV, do you mean that I just do not have to update the dimensions line "3 4 2", and simply append new data? If this is the case, I should not care about whether to save the matrix as a row vector or as a column vector, since row's and column's numbers are constant, and the only changing one is the third (time) dimension.

Comment: That is correct, it is just a matter of readability by a non-computer ;)

Comment: If anybody can write his comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Pietro it does not apply when you do that! If each block is its own file, then you know the size when you write it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I would know the block size, but not the number of blocks.

Comment: @Pietro yes, you would, its the number of files.

Comment: @AnderBiguri - No, I would not, because the blocks would arrive in the future, in an unknown number.

Comment: @Pietro correct, but why would you want to know or record that? Most systems simply record until finished, and the length is in the number of files, there is no way to know the future in any case. Now, opening and rewriting a file, that takes enormous resources in comparison to everything else in a computer, and that is a thin that you want to avoid to do unnecesarily.

Comment: @AnderBiguri - I understand your point, but in my case I have to plot all the available data and then wait for the new ones to arrive, and plot them as soon as they themselves are available.

Comment: I really do not see an issue with that in the way I am describing it, but anyway, you got your answer, hope it works well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know the size of first two dimensions, you can simply append the new time step (or time steps block) as a column-, or better for readability, row-vector.

```
A = rand(3, 4, 100);
Nblock = 5;  % number of time steps to be written as a block
fmt = [repmat('%.4f \t', [1, size(A, 1)*size(A, 2)]), '\n']; % or whatever format you want to write your data in

fid = fopen('test.txt', 'a');
fprintf(fid, 'Your header');
for i = 1:size(A, 3)/Nblock
    idx = (i - 1)*Nblock;
    for j = 1:Nblock
        fprintf(fid, fmt, reshape(A(:, :, idx + j), [1, size(A, 1)*size(A, 2)]));
    end
end
fclose(fid);
```

Note that this is written in Matlab, and some commands might change in Octave.